# Kaplan Meier curve after IPTW

Tags: r

I want to use IPTW to find the effects of a medication on cardiovascular death (1), which competes with non-cardiovascular death (2) and survival (0).
After the IPTW, I would like to do a competing risk analysis to find the effect of the medication on cardiovascular death and plot the resulting Kaplan Meier curve.

This is my start

```
library(tableone)
library(crr)
library(ipw)
library(sandwich)
library(survey)
treatment<-as.numeric(df$treatment==1)
#propensity score model
psmodel<-glm(treatment ~ age + sex, data=df )

ps<-predict(psmodel, type="response")


#weights
weight<-ifelse(treatment==1,1/(ps),1/(1-ps))


age<-as.numeric(df$age)
sex<-as.numeric(df$sex==1)

cov1 <-cbind(age,sex, weight, treatment)
ftime <-df$Survival
fstatus<-df$Outcome

competingrisk<-crr(ftime, fstatus, cov1,  failcode=2)
summary(competingrisk)
```

My dataset looks like this but with 500 lines.

```
structure(list(Outcome = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2), Survival = c(7, 13, 14, 8, 9, 15, 14, 16, 
14, 3, 7, 13, 14, 8, 9, 15, 16, 4), treatment = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), age = c(59, 58, 57, 
56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42), 
    BMI = c(25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 25, 
    24, 23, 22, 21, 20), sex = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: You need to add library(cmprsk) for the crr() function. As far as I can see, you cannot use the ipwtm() function from ipw package without treatment start and duration values. Compare the haartind data in that package with yours.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added the crr function to the script. Now I amjust wondering how to plot the Kaplan Meyer Curve that is adjusted to the IPTW.

Comment: The library is called cmprsk, not crr. Did you look at the harrtind data in the ipw package, under the documentation for ipwtm()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Kaplan-Meier plot is very naive to multiple covariates, and to competing risks. I highly doubt it is the best way to analyse your data in this instance, however it could be used to investigate and so here is the solution.

If you want to find the four Kaplan-Meier curves for the two events, you can use the following code:

```
library(survival)

#create a KM model
mod1 <- survfit(Surv(Survival,Outcome==1)~treatment,data=df)

#plot it
plot(mod1,
     conf.int=TRUE, #show confidence intervals
     col=c("red","green") #treatment=0 is red
     )

#see ?plot.survfit for more parameters

mod2 <- survfit(Surv(Survival,Outcome==2)~treatment,data=df)

#plot it
plot(mod2,
     conf.int=TRUE, #show confidence intervals
     col=c("red","green") #treatment=0 is red
)
```

However, as stated above, KM plots are naive to competing risks (the probabilities do not take the other event into consideration and so at certain time points, you can have that the probabilities of the two events sum to more than 100%).You would likely be better plotting the Cumulative Incidence Function (or CIF), which does take into account the competing risks. The `cmprsk` package has the `cuminc()` function for this.

```
library(cmprsk)
cif <- cuminc(df$Survival,df$Outcome,df$treatment)

plot(cif)
# See ?plot.cuminc for more parameters
```

However, I find these base plots to be quite unappealing, and so would highly recommend using the `survminer` package which utilises `ggplot2` to create better plots:

```
library(survminer)

ggsurvplot(mod1)
ggsurvplot(mod2)

ggcompetingrisks(cif)
```

If you wish to *analyse* the data and find the effects of a treatment, using the IPTW, you can use the `crr()` function as in your question and this will return the subdistribution proportional hazard regression coefficients (i.e. the results of a Fine & Gray model). These can be interpreted in much the same way that of a Cox proportional hazard analysis can be (whilst accounting for the competing risks). Bear in mind that the IPTW is not a panacea and therefore these results may still be non-causal.

Once you have the Fine & Gray model results from `crr()`, you can create a plot of the subdistributions across the two treatments by using the following code (assuming you have made the `competingrisk` object above)

```
cov2 <- matrix(c(0,1),ncol=1)
colnames(cov2) <- "treatment"

cr_pred <- predict(competingrisk,cov2)

plot(cr_pred)
# see ?plot.predict.crr for parameters
```

A few good resources are:

- [This blogpost by Emily Zabor](https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html)
- [Tutorial in Biostatistics by Putter et al.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/sim.2712)

Comment: This is exactly, what I have been looking for, thank you so much. Only one question remains. I would love to correct the cumulative incidence plot for the weight, that I created using the IPTW. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think there is currently a way to do this within R. The `cuminc()` function doesn't take a `weights` parameter and it's underlying algorithm is done in FORTRAN. However Bolch et al (https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-017-0367-8) provides an algorithm in their Appendix for doing this which you could possibly implement (they used SAS for their actual computations though).